# Bootstrap-select with multiple option doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6, bootstrap-select

I'm developing a web application using Angular 6. I used the library **bootstrap-select** (by Silvio Mureto) to implement a combo-box (with additional possibilities to customize). I have a problem: when I set the `multiple` attribute, graphically the behavior is right (all the selected strings appear inside the input box, together). The problem is that the value connected with my `ngModel` (used to get the data with 2-way binding) it's always only one (and always corresponds to the **first value displayed inside the box**, although there are other values in it!).
This is the code:

```
<select
   class="form-control selectpicker show-tick"
   data-width="200px"
   multiple
   title="my_title"
   name = "name"
   [(ngModel)] = "value"
   (ngModelChange) = "onChange($event)"
>
    <option value="1">Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Value 2</option>
    <option value="2">Value 3</option>

</select>
```

This is the result (graphically it's exactly as I would like):

[image]

But, as you can see, with each click to add a new value, the `value` object is always and only associated with `1` (because `Value 1` is the first in the list and doesn't seem to matter that the other two values are present).
The console log (object `value`):

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You change the `value` attribute of the options?

```
<option value="1">Value 1</option>
<option value="2">Value 2</option>
<option value="3">Value 3</option>
```

Currently you have 3 `option` elements all with `value="1"`. So your output is exactly what you told angular to select.

**edit**: as you edited the question, we probably need to see the `onChange` method to help understand the problem better

Comment: sorry for the distraction. The problem remains anyway

Comment: the method onChange simply prints $event in the console

Comment: @claudioz , Your problem is not inside this code, I cannot reproduce the bug, look here: https://imgur.com/a/wGvZNYU